# Python/Django - using a view method on an upload file

Tags: python, django

I have this view:

```
def index(request):
    file = open("SK ✌✌.txt", encoding="UTF-8")
    data = file.read()
    file.close()

    lines = data.split("\n")
    ...More code...
```

In this view i open a file from the very first moment the app starts and i do some work on the file, is a story, and when i start the server and go to http://127.0.0.1:8000/(Name Of The App), i see all the work that i have done on that file.

What i want to do is to do that same work, starting with the reading of the file, BUT i want to do that with the file that the user uploads in that moment. I have this that i took from bootstrap:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFile">File input</label>
    <input type="file" id="exampleInputFile">
</div>
```

I guess i have to use in some way the id of the input but i`m not really sure how to pass this file that the user uploads in the ui to the method that i have in my views.py

Any help will be really appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have a `name` attribute in your `<input>` template code.

```
<input type="file" id="exampleInputFile" name="some_file">
```

Then to access the file in your view, you need to use  [`request.FILES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) attribute.

As per the [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.FILES) on `HttpRequest.FILES` attribute:

> A dictionary-like object containing all uploaded files. Each key in
>   `FILES` is the `name` from the `<input type="file" name="" />`. Each 
>   value in `FILES` is an `UploadedFile`.

Your code should be something like:

```
def index(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        uploaded_file = request.FILES['some_file'] # get the uploaded file
        # do something with the file
```

**Note:** `request.FILES` will only contain data if the request method was `POST` and the `<form>` that posted to the request had `enctype="multipart/form-data`. Otherwise, `FILES` will be a blank dictionary-like object.